# Fill list using Counter with 0 values

Tags: python, django

Is possible to have a count of how many times a value appears in a given list, and have '0' if the item is not in the list?

I have to use `zip` but the first list have 5 items and the other one created using count, have only 3. That's why I need to fill the other two position with 0 values.

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what you want. Can you give sample input and the expected output?

Comment: Are you sure that you have to use `zip`?

Comment: For example: a = [a,b,c,d,e] and b = [1,4,3]. b is a list created using Counter in this example a contains 1 element, b contains 4 elements ..., d contains 0 elements and e 0 elements. 
What i want to achieve is: a = [a,b,c,d,e] and b = [1,4,3,0,0]. I have to return a zip of a and b to my template but at the time in my template i'm having a = [a,b,c] and b = [1,4,3]

Comment: @Samwise yes, i have to iterate both in a unique {%for..%}

Comment: Your example makes no sense -- how does `a` contain itself, and why do you say `b` contains 4 elements when it clearly contains 3 elements?  You might need to provide some actual code.

Comment: Note that there's a difference between counting the number of items in a list and the number of times **each value** appears in the list!  Your example sounds a bit like you just want a list that's the `len` of the elements of another list, e.g. `b = [len(e) for e in a]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your purpose with itertools zip_longest.
With zip_longest, you can zip two lists of different lengths, just that the missing corresponding values will be filled with 'None'. You may define a suitable fill values as i have done below.

```
from itertools import zip_longest
a = ['a','b','c','d','e']
b = [1,4,3]
final_lst = list(zip_longest(a,b, fillvalue=0))
final_dict = dict(list(zip_longest(a,b, fillvalue=0))) #you may convert answer to dictionary if you wish
```

**ELSE**

If what you are trying to do is count the number of times items in a reference list appear in another list(taking record also of reference items that don't appear in the other list), you may use dictionary comprehension:

```
ref_list = ['a','b','c','d','e']#reference list
other_list = ['a','b','b','d','a','d','a','a','a']
count_dict = {n:other_list.count(n) for n in ref_list}
print (count_dict)
```

> Output

```
{'a': 5, 'b': 2, 'c': 0, 'd': 2, 'e': 0}
```

Comment: You are right. I've achieved my goal. Thank you very much. +1

Comment: UPDATE: The second one example gaves me:
 count() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Can you share your implementation?

Comment: Do not mind, i've solved. The problem was that one a list of values was a result of a queryset. So i converted to a list and everything was ok

Answer (score 0):

Use `collections.Counter`, and then call `get` with a default value of 0 to see how many times any given element appears:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counts = Counter([1, 2, 3, 1])
>>> counts.get(1, 0)
2
>>> counts.get(2, 0)
1
>>> counts.get(5, 0)
0
```

Comment: I'm using Counter already and it works, but as i want to have:  a = [a,b,c,d,e] and b = [1,4,3,0,0], Counter returns [1,4,3]. If there are more than one element Counter works correctly, but if an element is not present, Counter does not 'count' it and returns a list as i mentioned above.

Comment: Call `.get(element, 0)` on the Counter for each `element` you're interested in.  It'll give you 0 if the element isn't present.

Comment: I am writing a dynamic function, i cannot use get. a is a list resulting of a query, b is a list created by Counter, then i have to retrieve in my template a is present (as in example above) 1 time, b is present 4 times.

Comment: There's no reason you can't call `get` inside a function.  The example you provide isn't illuminating because it makes no sense.  :\

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count how many times a value appears in a list, you could do this:

```py
def count_in_list(list_,value):
    count=0
    for e in list_:
        if e==value:
            count+=1
    return count
```

And use the code like this:

```py
MyList=[1,3,1,1,1,1,1,2]
count_in_list(MyList,1)
```

Output:

`6`

This will work without any additional things such as imports.